# Backtick/accent_grave is overwritten by § char

Tags: keyboard, language, input-source

When I type the backtick char the output becomes § on my keyboard. I have tested this in multiple apps and I have also double checked in Karabiner-Event (KE) viewer to make sure that it is the backtick that I am typing. In KE it sais the character I'm typing is 'accent_grave_and_tile'. I think this means that my keyboard is outputting the backtick but somehow it is being converted to the § symbol.

1. Language is set to english in sys pref
2. Keyboard input source is set to U.S
3. I have tried switching btw multiple input sources
4. Tested multiple languages under text &  languages in sys pref

Thanks,
// hjalle

Comment: Have you done things with Karabiner to modify your layout?  American ANSI keyboards make backtik via the key to the left of the one, but European ISO keyboards make backtik via the key to the right of left shift.  Which of these are you expecting??   If your machine is confusing ANSI and ISO, there is some info at https://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html

Comment: This is almost certainly due to your software keyboard layout. Based on you saying you're using the US software keyboard layout, I assume you have an ANSI physical keyboard layout? [See this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/Physical_keyboard_layouts_comparison_ANSI_ISO_JIS.png) to confirm, paying attention to the existence/position of the keys highlighted in red. If your keyboard *is* ANSI, and you have set the US keyboard layout in Keyboard preferences, then the key immediately to the left of the `1` key should be the `\`` key.

Comment: @lx07 You assume OP has an ISO keyboard with a European Mac layout printed on the keys.

Comment: @JivanPal - you are right - I suppose I did.  I have a French ISO keyboard and looked in *System Preferences* to get US layout and it looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6ktR.png) rather than like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEQUI.png) which has no key between `Z` and `Shift` (ANSI I suppose).  Would help to know what keyboard OP has though.

Comment: Sorry guys for taking up your time. The solution to my problem was to run through the keyboard setup assistant again on my mac. I did not understand this at first. Now everything works as it should! :)